# Remap control key in gnome-terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, xmodmap

I just installed Ubuntu to get more familiar with it since I'll be using it in a new job shortly. I use Macs at home and in my current job, so I'd like to make it as Mac-like as possible. I've remapped the command and control characters using the following .xmodmap:

```
remove control = Control_L Control_R
remove mod4 = Super_L Super_R
add control = Super_L Super_R
add mod4 = Control_L Control_R
```

Which works great for everything except the terminal, since Ctrl-C is now mapped to CMD-C, and still conflicts with what I'd like to use to copy. Is there any way I can remap the Control key just for the terminal? I'm willing to consider gnome-terminal alternatives if required.

Answer (score 1):

I have a mac keyboard plugged to my linux box. I have remapped the Command key to Alt. There's a way to tell Firefox to use Alt as Ctrl, so now Command T, Command W works as expected, Command C / Command V works in firefox.

I'm also trying to mimic the Mac Terminal shortcut in gnome-terminal, one important thing is to disconnect Alt to start the Menu.